# Missing separator in Makefile

Tags: makefile

So here's the thing.

I'm trying to build pngwriter. In the makefile there's a line saying:

```
include make.include
```

The file make.include has the function to specify the platform used via a symlink, it has just one line:

```
make.include.linux
```

(there's a file in the same directory called make.include.linux which has some necessary settings. And by the way, I'm doing this on Windows with MinGW)

in the msys shell, when I do **make**, it says:

```
make.include:1: *** missing separator. Stop.
```

I've looked at other missing separator posts and they're about spaces/tabs, which I think it's not the case here. I've searched about makefiles, symlinks, separators and could solve it.

Please help!

EDIT! OK, so make.include.linux isn't a command, it's a file whose contents need to be  included in the original makefile. The make.include should be, as I read, a symlink to make.include.linux.

Comment: What's `make.include.linux`?

Comment: it's a file, containing different data. I guess it's a command, as you named it below. I'll look into targets, recipees more.

Comment: Ok, so did you try making it a symlink?

Comment: I don't know how. What to write inside the file?

Answer (score 0):

What you have there isn't valid `make` syntax.  Commands can only be run as part of a target recipe.  In your case it seems like what you want is:

```
all:
    make.include.linux
```

Assuming that `make.include.linux` is a command, and not something else.  Make sure the indentation is a tab character.

Comment: if you would please see my EDIT. make.include is not a command, it's a file

Comment: OK, so it sounds like what you want is just to change that file to say `include make.include.linux`, or alternately just delete `make.include` and recreate it as a symbolic link: `ln -s make.include.linux make.include`.

Comment: If I put "include make.include.linux" in make.include, it says:

"../make.include:1: make.include.linux: No such file or directory
make [1]: *** No rule to make target 'make.include.linux'. Stop."

But symlinking seems to do the job. Thank you.